# Use WiFi access point (Asus EA-AC87) to connect Internet through 4G of smartphone?

Tags: wireless-networking, gateway

Considering:

- a 4G LTE smartphone (Windows Phone)
- a WiFi access point (Asus EA-AC87) with RJ45 sockets
- several desktops that are connected to the access point with Ethernet wires.

can one use the access point as a bridge to connect the desktops to the Internet using the smartphone's 4G access?

I can access the access point configuration at 192.168.1.1 but cannot see a way to connect to the smartphone's WiFi. The access point seems behaving as a WiFi provider and not as a WiFi client.

Comment: solved: see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [product website](https://www.asus.com/Networking/EAAC87/), Wi-Fi station (client) functionality *is* present in the standard firmware – it's called "Media Bridge" mode by Asus.

In various other devices, this feature might be added by third-party firmware (LEDE/OpenWRT), since the hardware is (at least I'd expect) always compatible and it's just not exposed in the web config.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the 4G smartphone must, for WiFi, be capable of emitting in the 5 GHz band.
If the smartphone only emits in the 2.4 GHz band, the Asus EA-AC87 won't see it.